# accessing an arrayed name through getelementsbyname

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a series of elements on a form:

```
<input type="radio" name="options[0]" value="Mens" />Mens&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="options[0]" value="Womens" />Womens&nbsp;<hr>
<input type="radio" name="options[1]" value="XL" />XL&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="options[1]" value="L" />L&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="options[1]" value="M" />M&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="options[1]" value="S" />S&nbsp;<hr />
<input type="checkbox" size="16" name="options[2]" value="Printed Name" />Printed Name
```

How can I access the values of the radio button for my validation routine?

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll`

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name^=options]');
```

`[name^=options]` matches elements whose `name` begins with `options`.

You can then loop over `radios`.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. As is the answer from Ouroberus. Presumably the type=checkbox will work to get the values of the checkboxes as well.

Comment: The main difference is that mine gets all the radio buttons, his just gets the selected button from one group. You'll need to repeat it for each radio group. And you're correct about how to get the checkboxes.